# Reading txt file in C++ to strings and floats

Tags: c++, stream

I need to read a *.txt file. It contains words and numbers, and it looks like this:

firstword:12,13.0secondword18.7thirdword2,3,89

I need to extract the words as strings, and the numbers as floats. The main problem I cannot solve is there no delimiters before "words" (otherwise I'd use getline).

Thank you!

Note: the words does not contain numbers, for example, the word 'num1' is impossible.

Comment: Can the words include numerals, like "Apollo13"? if so, then the format is ambiguous; if not, then you can parse the file one character at a time.

Comment: No, words doesn't contain numbers.

Comment: Try a `stringstream`, maybe.

Comment: @Maria: you need to process it char after char: `if(c >= '0' && c <= '9')` `c` is digit.

Comment: :( I understand. I though maybe there is some more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

With `sstream`, it more often requires a delimiter, There is none in your file.

By using functions found in the standard c library, you can do it character by character without a delimiter. And it is not elegant.

This is one way of extracting words and doubles from a text file `text.txt` contaning `firstword:12,13.0secondword18.7thirdword2,3,89`.

This solution uses the funtion `isalpha()` to extract anything alphabet related and stores it in the array `extractedWords[]`.

For doubles, it uses `isdigit()` and `atof()` to extract anything number related and stores it in the array `extractedDoubles[]`.

```
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>

#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

char mainBuffer[1024]={' '};
size_t fsize ;
string extractedWords[100];
double extractedDoubles[100]={0};


string buf2str(const char* buffer);
void loadFileToBuffer(char *filename);
void extractWords();
void extractFloats();



int main(){

    loadFileToBuffer("text.txt" );
    extractWords();  
    extractFloats();
    cout<<"\n";
    return 0;
}                                                                             



string buf2str(const char* buffer){
    return string(buffer);
}


void loadFileToBuffer(char *filename){
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename);

    infile.read(mainBuffer, sizeof mainBuffer);
    if (infile.eof()){
         fsize = infile.gcount();
         cout<<"fsize = "<<fsize<<" , data =  " << mainBuffer <<" \n ";
    }
    else if (infile.fail()){
        // some other error...
    }
    else{
        // buf must be full, but the file is larger...
    }
     infile.close();
}

void extractWords(){
    char character;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char shortBuffer[16]={' '};
    int seek=0;


     cout<<"\n";
    seek=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    while ( seek<=fsize ) {
        character=mainBuffer[seek];
        if ( isalpha(character) ) {
             shortBuffer[i]=character;
            i++;
        }
         else{
            shortBuffer[i]='\0';
            if (strlen(shortBuffer)>2){
                extractedWords[j]=buf2str(shortBuffer);
                i=0;
                j++;
            }
         } 
         seek++;
    }
    for(int ii=0;ii<j;ii++) cout<<extractedWords[ii] <<"\n";
    cout<<"\n";
}


void extractFloats(){
    char character;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char shortBuffer[16]={' '};
    double dValue=0;
    int seek=0;

    cout<<"\n";
    seek=0;
    i=0;
    j=0;

    while ( seek<=fsize ) {
        character=mainBuffer[seek];
        if ( isdigit(character) || character=='.' ){
              shortBuffer[i]=character;
              i++;
        }
        else{
             shortBuffer[i]='\0';
             dValue=atof(shortBuffer);
             if (dValue != 0) {
                 extractedDoubles[j]=dValue;
             j++;
             i=0;
             }           
        }
        seek++;
    }
    for(int ii=0;ii<j;ii++) cout <<extractedDoubles[ii]<<"\n";
    cout<<"\n";
}
```